# RegEx for 00:00 Time Format > 24

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, textbox

I've found many RegEx Samples. For example this:

```
^(20|21|22|23|[01]\d|\d)(([:][0-5]\d){1,2})$
```

It's possible to use 9:00 or 09:00. The problem is, it's limited to 24 hours, but I need it to validate duration, not an exact time, so It could be bigger than 24 hours.

I have a TextBox which gets validated with a RegularExpressionValidator.
I have no clue about RegEx and couldn't find some kind of generator.

Can you help me to get this done?

Comment: what is correct and incorrect data for you? is 99999999:00 allowed? is 0000001:00:00 allowed?

Comment: If its longer than 24 hours it should fall over to 1 day.

Comment: @MrFox Nope. Just duration. Nothing 1 day format. Just hours and minutes.

Comment: @Default Just 09:00, 9:00, maybe 9.00 or 9. In a range a user would tape in. All other things can be catched server-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
^\d+(:[0-5]\d){1,2}$
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limited to regex you can use [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) and let that [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx) the time for you. Then you can just access the different properties for `Days`, `Hours`, `Minutes` and so on as you please.

To me, this is much easier than maintaining regex

Comment: I know. But I'm limited by regex --> RegularExpressionValidator.